# Show that a differential equations depends continuously on parameter $\mu$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation depending on the parameter
$$
\dot{x} = F(x;\mu), 
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu$ is in $\mathbb{R}^p$, and $F$ is a $C^1$ function jointly in $x$ and $\mu$. Let $\phi^t(x;\mu)$ be the solution with $\phi^0(x;\mu) = x$. Prove that $\phi^t(x;\mu)$ depends continuously on the parameter $\mu$.

My idea was to go as follows:

Fix $t$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $F$ is $C^1$ in $\mu$, it is also continuous in $\mu$. So let $\delta > 0$ be such that $\|\mu_1 - \mu_2\| < \delta$ implies that $\|F(x(t) ; \mu_1) - F(x(t) ; \mu_2)\| < \frac{\epsilon}{t}$. In integral form we can write $\phi^t(x ; \mu) = x_0 + \int_0^t F(\phi^s(x ; \mu);\mu) ds$, with $x_0 = x$ in this case. Then
$$
\| \phi^t(x ; \mu_1) - \phi^t(x ; \mu_2) \| \leq \int_0^t \|F(\phi^s(x ; \mu_1);\mu_1) - F(\phi^s(x ; \mu_2);\mu_2)\|ds, 
$$
But how to proceed from here? Am I on the right track at all?

Comment: If you fix the situation so that $F$ is jointly Lipschitz on a sufficiently large domain, then $$\|F(x_1,μ_1)-F(x_2,μ_2)\|\le L(\|x_1-x_2\|+\|μ_1-μ_2\|),$$ which should allow to apply the Grönwall lemma.

Comment: Can we do this by considering an open ball $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^p$ such that $x_1,x_2,\mu_1,\mu_2 \in U$?

Comment: Yes, any open set should work, you can also take a tube around some fixed solution. The difference is, as always, for how long the local solutions exist inside that set.